# How can I integrate CalDAV and CardDAV

Tags: iphone, mobile, caldav

I am trying to allow people (from a URL) to connect to a calender/contacts from their iPhone, Blackbury or Android phone - what is the best way to do this?

I've had a bit of a read and it seems that CalDAV and CardDAV are the best way to integrate calenders/contacts, but how exactly can I do this? The internet seems to lack a standard way of how you can integrate this into a number of devices.

Which mobile devices support them? And is it possible to just provide a URL and then the calender/contacts just automatically sync!?

Comment: This is very simple. I just created a detailed tutorial about this and mayne other things. Home it helps you out: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/

Answer (score 0):

All of this assumes you have some sort of Groupware server setup somewhere which acts as the repository for this information.

For opensource you might want to look at a product called [Sogo](http://www.sogo.nu). Apple also do a [caldav/carddav](http://trac.calendarserver.org/) server written in python. They expect you to buy a mac server but you can download the code and run it from a pc or linux box. There's a heap of paid-for [groupware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software#Groupware%3a_Web_based_solutions).

You might want to check out the "opensource" client software written by the same kids who develop Sogo caled [funambol](http://www.funambol.com/). This claims to be x-mobile (all the ones youve mentioned anyway).

The idea behind all the *DAV protocols is that yes everything is done by Uri (this was actually specced by Tim Berners Lee in his draft for the web).

I've just been through this very same process and found only emerging standards, of which *DAV are the de facto ones IMO. HTC use MS active sync on my HD2 to sync my Gmail. Go figure!

Comment: Hi, All I really want is an example. I want to build a service myself in my system. Do you know of any examples ?

Comment: As far as I know the guys behind sogo are very different from the funambol people. Funambol does work with sogo though.

Answer (score 0):

**Bedework** is **CalDAV/CardDAV** server that allows you to hook your `iPhone/iCal` calendar and events.

I have used it and it gives you an url to sign in with in you phone calendar. The Bedework is a server you could install on you machine (it is provided with documentation; this is a good point to start with).

Android natively does not support **Bedework**. In order for Android to support the **CalDAV** you have to install an application that supports **CalDAV**, but I do not know if they work with **Bedewrok** or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of android you could try using the CalendarProvider and the ContactProvider. You could refer to this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html